# Yii validation rules ignores 'on' or 'except'

Tags: forms, validation, yii2, scenarios

I faced with a next problem.
I'm trying to validate field in different ways, depening on action: phone is should be unique on user create, and should not on user edit, so:

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['owner_id','card_code', 'name', 'phone', 'birthday','language', 'last_ip'], 'required'],
        [['account_id'], 'required', 'on' => 'update'],
        [['account_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Accounts::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['account_id' => 'id'], 'on' => 'update'],

        [['owner_id', 'account_id', 'active', 'last_carwash'], 'integer'],
        [['birthday', 'last_active', 'last_update', 'last_sync'], 'safe'],
        [['car_number', 'role', 'status'], 'string'],
        [['card_code', 'car_number', 'name', 'phone', 'password', 'auth_key', 'language'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['last_ip'], 'ip'],
        [['name'], 'string', 'min' => 5],

        ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6, 'message' => Yii::t('app', 'The password must contain at least 6 symbols.')/*, 'on' => 'create'*/],
        ['password', 'match', 'pattern' => '/[A-z]/', 'message' => Yii::t('app', 'The password must contain at least 1 letter.')/*, 'on' => 'create'*/],
        ['password', 'match', 'pattern' => '/[0-9]/', 'message' => Yii::t('app', 'The password must contain at least 1 number.')/*, 'on' => 'create'*/],
        [['password'], 'required', 'on' => 'create'],
        [['phone'], 'validatePhone', 'except' => 'update'/*, 'skipOnEmpty' => false*/],
        [['email'], 'email'],
        [['email'], 'validateEmail', 'except' => 'update'/*, 'skipOnEmpty' => false*/],
    ];
}
```

I'm using AJAX validation:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'validationUrl' => \yii\helpers\Url::to('/user/validation'),
    ]);
```

Validation actions:

```
public function validatePhone()
  
  {
        $phone = preg_filter( '/[^0-9]*/','', $this->phone );
        $u = Users::findOne(['phone' => $phone]);
        if($u)
            /*if($this->id != $u->id)*/
                $this->addError('phone', Yii::t('app', 'This phone is already taken.'));
    }
    public function validateEmail()
    {
        $email = $this->email;
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            $this->addError('email', Yii::t('app', 'Please, enter correct email'));
    
        $u = Users::findOne(['email' => $email]);
        if($u)
            $this->addError('email', Yii::t('app', 'This email is already taken.'));
    }
```

In controller actions

```
   public function actionCreate()
        {
            if ( Yii::$app->request->post() != NULL ) {
            $data = Yii::$app->request->post('Users');
            $model = new Users;
            $model->scenario = 'create';
           ...//lots of a code
            if(!$model->validate()){var_dump($model->errors);exit;}
            $model->save();
             return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

    public function actionUpdate($id)
        {
          $model = $this->findModel($id);
          $model->scenario = 'update';
          $model->setScenario('update');// same as ^ , but who knows...
         $data = Yii::$app->request->post();

         if( $data )
         {
        ...//lots of code
           if(!$model->validate()){var_dump($model->errors);exit;}
           $model->save();
             return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
          }
         return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
          ]);
       }

public function actionValidation()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

            $model = new \app\models\Users();
            if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
                return \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
        throw new \yii\web\BadRequestHttpException( Yii::t('app', 'Bad request.') );
    }

    protected function findModel($id)
        {
            if (($model = Users::findOne($id)) !== null) {
                return $model;
            }
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
        }
```

Scenario:

```
public function scenarios()
    {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios['create'] = ['account_id', 'card_code', 'name', 'phone', 'email', 'car_number', 'birthday', 'role', 'password'];
        $scenarios['update'] = ['account_id', 'card_code', 'name', 'phone', 'email', 'car_number', 'birthday', 'role', 'password'];
        return $scenarios;
    }
```

but it doesn't work at all at any forms.

If i delete `'on' => 'create'` it works fine, but in ALL forms, what is unwanted.
So how can i use validatePhone and validateEmail only in create scenario?

Comment: The `on` functionality is well tested inside the framework suite so it must be something on your side. Please update your question with the rest of the code for actionCreate and actionUpdate.

Comment: @Bizley, added more code. Thank you for you attention.

Comment: There is a lot of redundant code but I don't see anything really wrong. Remember that inline validators (like your `validatePhone` and `validateEmail`) will not work if their attributes are empty or have some errors already (you need to set `skipOnError` and `skipOnEmpty` to `false` to prevent it). Anyway, at what point your validation doesn't work? At AJAX validation triggered by client or at the server validation? If former - add the code for `actionValidation`.

Comment: Added actionValidation controller code. Validation works good, but i want it to work in one scenario only (create). But currently it works everywhere, e.g. both create and update. Adding `'on' => 'create'` or `'except'=>'update'` has no effect or brokes validation everywhere

Comment: But look at your actionValidation code - there is no scenario set there, isn't it the reason why you are claiming it's not working?

Comment: Code `$data = Yii::$app->request->bodyParams;
            $scenario = $data['Users']['scenario'];
            $model = new \app\models\Users();
                $model->scenario = $scenario;` didn't help. Anyway, i sloved this problem in another way without scenarios.